# Negative string value in hash ruby

Tags: ruby, string, hash

I'm trying to use a negative value in a string which is in a hash.

```
{"amount"=>"-50.01", "currency"=>"CAD"}
```

If I write `transaction.amount` I get 0.5001E2, if I use `to_f` I get 50.01.

I'm trying to extract the -50 value.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What is "transaction"? Is it vanilla Ruby or Rails perhaps?

Comment: can't reproduce

Comment: `to_f.round`???

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Your question does not make any sense it its current format. (What is `transaction`?!)

Comment: OK he didn't explicitly state what transaction was but it's pretty obvious from the code..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
transaction['amount']
```

For example

```
a = {"amount"=>"-50.01", "currency"=>"CAD"}
```

Then

```
a['amount']
```

returns '-50.01'

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked!!

Comment: No worries!! :)